# I do not know how to change EUC-KR to UCS2

Tags: c

I have a question.
The data that came in UART is in EUC-KR format. I want to convert it to UCS2. But I do not know which function to use. Can anyone tell me if I know how?
I did some research and found that there is a wbtowc function.
 
I tried using the wbtowc function in MFC and it works, but it doesn't seem to work in the embedded environment.

The development environment is Keil uvision5, the language is C, and the g ++ compiler is used.

I have to send SMS message and I have to use UCS2 to send it in Korean. Data received in EUC-KR should be converted.

It works fine without any errors when compiled, but the values in the converted buffer are zero.

Comment: Do you mean `mbtowc`? That will only work if your current locale is EUC-KR, and it is not at all clear to me that your embedded environment has such a locale.

Comment: You will need to check which standard library Keil provides with μVision5 and what functions are available in it.